# How to test mongoose methods using sinon fakes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, sinon

I have the following arrangement of tests using sinon, mocha and chai:

```js
type ModelObject = {
    name: string;
    model: typeof Categoria | typeof Articulo | typeof Usuario;
    fakeMultiple: () => object[];
    fakeOne: (id?: string) => object;
}

const models: ModelObject[] = [
    {
        name: 'categorias',
        model: Categoria,
        fakeMultiple: () => fakeMultiple({ creator: oneCategoria }),
        fakeOne: oneCategoria
    },
    {
        name: 'articulos',
        model: Articulo,
        fakeMultiple: () => fakeMultiple({ creator: oneArticulo }),
        fakeOne: oneArticulo
    },
    {
        name: 'usuarios',
        model: Usuario,
        fakeMultiple: () => fakeMultiple({ creator: oneUsuario }),
        fakeOne: oneUsuario
    }
];

const randomModel = models[Math.floor(Math.random() * models.length)];

describe(`v1/${randomModel.name}`, function () {

    this.afterEach(function () {
        sinon.restore();
    });

    context.only("When requesting information from an endpoint, this should take the Model of the requested endpoint and query the database for all the elements of that model", function () {
        it.only(`Should return a list of elements of ${randomModel.name} model`, function (done) {
            const fakes = randomModel.fakeMultiple();

            const findFake = sinon.fake.resolves({ [randomModel.name]: fakes });

            sinon.replace(randomModel.model, 'find', findFake);
            
            chai.request(app)
                .get(`/api/v1/${randomModel.name}`)
                .end(
                    (err, res) => {
                        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                        expect(res.body.data).to.be.an('object');
                        expect(res.body.data).to.have.property(randomModel.name);
                        expect(res.body.data[randomModel.name]).to.have.lengthOf(fakes.length);
                        expect(findFake.calledOnce).to.be.true;
                        done();
                    }
                )
        });
}}
```

I use this to test an endpoint that arbitrary returns information about a given model. In my controllers, I'm using a dynamic middleware to determine which model is going to be queried, for example, if the route consumed is "api/v1/categorias", it will query for Categorias model. If the route consumed is "api/v1/articulos", it will query for Articulos model, and so on.

To make the query, i use the following service:

```js
import { Articulo } from '../models/articulo';
import { Usuario } from '../models/usuario';
import { Categoria } from '../models/categoria';
import logger from '../config/logging';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';


const determineModel = (model: string): Model<any> => {
    switch (model) {
        case 'articulos':
            return Articulo;
        case 'usuarios':
            return Usuario;
        case 'categorias':
            return Categoria;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Model ${model} not found`);
    }
};

export const getInformation = async (schema: string, page: number, limit: number) => {
    try {
        const model = determineModel(schema);
        const data = await model.find().skip((page - 1) * limit).limit(limit);

        const dataLength = await model.find().countDocuments();

        return {
            data,
            total: dataLength,
        };

    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }

};
```

The problem here lies when running my tests, it seems that is unable to run the .skip() and .limit() methods for my model.find()

```
error: model.find(...).skip is not a function
TypeError: model.find(...).skip is not a function
```

I think that I need to fake those methods, because when running the same test without skip and limit, it works as a charm. My problem lies in the fact that I don't know how to fake those, or to see if my guess is correct.

As a note, I have default params for the variables **page** and **limit** (1 and 15 respectively) so I'm not passing empty values to the methods.